# Restricting String length in data type values in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I'm trying to represent a car licence plate with Haskell. The definition of the licence plate format is as follows:

1. Old licence plate was 5 digits alphanumeric long
2. New licence plate is made up of:

   - state of registration (N,S,E,W, and C)
   - district the car was registered in (1,2..20)
   - year and month of registration
   - a  random  sequence  of  three  alphanumeric  digits.

My attempt at the solution is as follows

```
import Data.Char
data Locality = N | S | E | W | C

data Reg = OldReg {code :: String} | NewReg {loc :: Locality,
            district :: Int,
            month :: Int,
            year :: Int,
            random:: String} 

currentYear =2020

createNewReg::Localitly->Int->Int->Int->String-> Maybe Reg
createNewReg l d m y r 
    | (d < 1) ||(d > 20)  = Nothing --district must be between 1 and 20
    | (m < 1) || (m > 12) = Nothing -- month must be between 1 and 12
    | (y >= 2020) && y<= currentYear = Nothing -- Year must be after new plates introduce and below or equal to current year 
    | length(r) /= 3 = Nothing  -- random sequence must be 3 digits long
    | not $foldl (&&) True $ map Data.Char.isAlpha r = Nothing --random sequence must be alphanumeric
    | otherwise = Just $NewReg l d m y r
```

I was wondering if there is a more "Haskell" solution to the problem? Can I make a data type that restricts these fields without having to use a different function to construct one?

Something like `NewData {random :: String (Alpha :3)}` to limit it to a alphanumeric string of length 3?

(*I know that wouldn't be anywhere near correct syntax but I hope you get the idea*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extend Haskell with all sorts of fancy features that may get you some of the way, but there's also some low-hanging fruits. As is typical in programming, these often come in the form of trade-offs. This is also the case here.

Programmers often use integers to represent numbers, even if these numbers are more like labels or IDs rather than numbers. If you don't do arithmetic on the numbers, they are candidates for a sum type instead.

For example, you could define months like this:

```
data Month =
  Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec
  deriving (Eq, Show, Ord, Enum, Bounded)
```

This is more type-safe than using an `Int` because you're constrained to only those twelve values. You also nicely sidestep the issue of whether `0` or `1` indicates January, etc.

You could do the same with the *district* value (not shown here).

Likewise, if you know that you always have three values, a list isn't the best data type. A tuple is better.

A partial improvement of the `Reg` data type, then, would be something like this:

```
data Reg =
    OldReg { code :: String }
  | NewReg { loc :: Locality,
             district :: Int,
             month :: Month,
             year :: Int,
             random :: (Char, Char, Char) }
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

This doesn't address all concerns, because `random` could still be populated with, say, `('1', '2', '2')`. It's also more difficult to come up with a type that correctly constrains the year, so you'll probably still need the smart constructor.

You might be able to do more, though. Normally, licence plates only allow upper-case letters. The smart constructor could check for lower-case letters and either reject them or convert them, or you could model the letters as a sum type with twenty-six values: `A | B | C | D | ...` etc.